# Not able to query dynamoDb data using GeoDataManager in Node

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, geohashing

I am trying to follow the very basic tutorial of Geo Library for Amazon DynamoDB given here https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb-geo.
Even after following the steps mentioned in link, my myGeoTableManager.queryRadius() call is not giving me any result.
Below are the steps that I follow.

I created the dynamoDB table with below script

```
require("dotenv").config();

var AWS= require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: process.env.accessKeyId, secretAccessKey: process.env.secretAccessKey, region: "us-east-1"});
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

const ddbGeo = require('dynamodb-geo');

const config = new ddbGeo.GeoDataManagerConfiguration(ddb, 'locationData');
config.hashKeyLength = 5;

const createTableInput = ddbGeo.GeoTableUtil.getCreateTableRequest(config);
 
// Tweak the schema as desired
createTableInput.ProvisionedThroughput.ReadCapacityUnits = 5;
 
console.log('Creating table with schema:');
console.dir(createTableInput, { depth: null });
 
// Create the table
ddb.createTable(createTableInput).promise()
    // Wait for it to become ready
    .then(function () { return ddb.waitFor('tableExists', { TableName: 'locationData' }).promise() })
    .then(function () { console.log('Table created and ready!') });
```

Then I insert and query data in dynamoDB using below script.

```
require("dotenv").config();

var AWS= require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: process.env.accessKeyId, secretAccessKey: process.env.secretAccessKey, region: "us-east-1"});
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

const ddbGeo = require('dynamodb-geo');

const config = new ddbGeo.GeoDataManagerConfiguration(ddb, 'locationData');
config.hashKeyLength = 5;

const myGeoTableManager = new ddbGeo.GeoDataManager(config);

myGeoTableManager.putPoint({
    RangeKeyValue: { S: '1234' }, 
    GeoPoint: { 
        latitude: 28.749472,
        longitude: 77.056534
    },
    PutItemInput: { 
        Item: { 
            country: { S: 'country1' }, 
            capital: { S: 'capital1' }
        },
    }
}).promise()
.then(function() { console.log('Insert Done!') });

myGeoTableManager.putPoint({
    RangeKeyValue: { S: '5678' }, 
    GeoPoint: { 
        latitude: 28.749999,
        longitude: 77.056999
    },
    PutItemInput: { 
        Item: { 
            country: { S: 'country2' }, 
            capital: { S: 'capital2' }
        },
    }
}).promise()
.then(function() { console.log('Insert Done!') });

myGeoTableManager.queryRadius({
    RadiusInMeter: 100000,
    CenterPoint: {
        latitude: 28.749888,
        longitude: 77.056888 
    }
  }).then((locations) => {
    console.log(locations);
  });
```

Even with exactly same latitude and longitude, myGeoTableManager.queryRadius() is giving me empty response.

Comment: Have you ever figured this out? i am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

There is a newer version `https://github.com/renet/dynamodb-geo-v3` available that supports AWS 3.* version.